# Magento 2 how convert package weight to Kilogram (KG)

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I have a custom shipping method in Magento 2, i successfully got the package weight by using this code in Model/Carrier.php :

```
$weight = $request->getPackageWeight();
```

but the default system measurement is not in KG or grams,is there any way to detect the type of measurement for package weight and convert it to KG?

Answer (score 1):

The weight unit is whatever is being used for shipping. You can sometimes control it in Stores> Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods. For example UPS has a choice of Lbs or Kgs;

For custom shipping method you need to check UPS code,

Answer (score 0):

By default the weight is abstract in Magento. It does not have a measuring unit. You can consider it what you want.
There are some shipping methods like UPS (as [Yogesh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156964/146) mentioned ) where you can state the measuring unit, but this does not autodetect anything. You are just telling UPS that you use LBS or KG, but you still have to be careful at what you input in for the products.
If you have mixed units there is no out of the box way to determine which is which.
You may need to add an attribute for the products to determine the measuring unit, and then you need to change the method `Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::composePackagesForCarrier` to take into account your measuring unit when retrieving the weight from a products. Convert everything to KG or what ever unit you need.